# sort numbers with the format #,###,###.## with datatables.js

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my country the convention for expressing numbers is to use the . as a thousands separator and the , as the decimal separator. an example of this would be: 25.367,212   I have been unable to make datatables.js sort any column that uses this formatting.

I am using the following extensions:

```
//formatted number sort
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "formatted-num-pre": function (a) {
    a = (a === "-" || a === "") ? 0 : a.replace(/[^\d\-\.]/g, "");
    return parseFloat(a);
  },

  "formatted-num-asc": function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  },

  "formatted-num-desc": function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
  }
});

//formatted number autodetection
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
    function (sData) {
      var deformatted = sData.replace(/[^\d\-\.\/a-zA-Z]/g, '');
      if ($.isNumeric(deformatted) || deformatted === "-") {
        return 'formatted-num';
      }
      return null;
    }
);
```

I have searched the datatables documentation and forums but have not found  a solution. any suggestions?  I am using jquery 1.9.1 and datatables 1.9.4

Comment: If you were using mRender and mData to change the format of your number, it would automatically sort by the data rather than the string (if i'm interpreting the documentation correctly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving this in the following way:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['numeric-comma-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    //remove the dots (.) from the string and then replaces the comma with a dot
  var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/, ".");
  var y = (b == "-") ? 0 : b.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/, ".");
  x = parseFloat(x);
  y = parseFloat(y);
  return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['numeric-comma-desc'] = function (a, b) {
  var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/, ".");
  var y = (b == "-") ? 0 : b.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/, ".");
  x = parseFloat(x);
  y = parseFloat(y);
  return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};

//numeric comma autodetect
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
            function (sData) {
   //include the dot in the sValidChars string (don't place it in the last position)
              var sValidChars = "0123456789-.,";
              var Char;
              var bDecimal = false;

              /* Check the numeric part */
              for (i = 0 ; i < sData.length ; i++) {
                Char = sData.charAt(i);
                if (sValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) {
                  return null;
                }

                /* Only allowed one decimal place... */
                if (Char == ",") {
                  if (bDecimal) {
                    return null;
                  }
                  bDecimal = true;
                }
              }

              return 'numeric-comma';
            }
        );
```